# avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM5": Access is denied

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm getting the error as follows

> Sketch uses 2952 bytes (9%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
> Global variables use 196 bytes (9%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1852 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM5": Access is denied.
> Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

The board I am using is Arduino Uno and checked the ports too. Also restarted and installed IDE again. But still not being able to deal with it.
I will be happy with the help!

Comment: Are you sure that COM5 is your Arduino Uno? On the device manager check if you unplug Arduino Uno, COM5 goes away.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows (if you are using windows), There are two things may caused the problem:

- go to device manager >> ports >> and Uninstall all ports related to Arduino (including the COM5). Then connect the arduino again and it install it again automatically.
- Make sure that you close all "serial monitor", before uploading the sketch.

Comment: I did that too. I even tried with Arduino cloud web editor. But no results.

Comment: I am sure about it. I am aware of the above mentioned method. And even tried with other ports. Still the error message is same.